# How to filter data date on start date and end date if i have a tabular data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to filter data date on start date and end date if i have a tabular data ?

Hi i m using jquery and javascript i have some data and i want to filter data in this table i m searching to google but not find any solution please help me now my code is this

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
                        
                         $('#submitAction').on('click', function(){
                            
                            var startDate = $('#startDate').val();
                            var endDate = $('#endDate').val();
                            alert("My Value is "+ startDate + endDate);
                            if((startDate == null || startDate == '') && (endDate == null || endDate == '')){
                            alert("Please fill the correct start and end date");
                        }else{
                            alert("Success" +startDate + endDate);
                        }
                             
                             return false;
                            
                        
                        });
     
     
 });
```

```css
body{
                        font-family: arial;
                        font-size: 14px;
                        color:#000000;
                    }
                        .table-bordered {
                            border: 1px solid #ddd;
                            width: 800px;
                            background-color: transparent;
                            border-spacing: 0;
                            border-collapse: collapse;
                            font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
                            font-size: 14px;
                            margin: 0 auto;
                        }
                        .table-bordered>thead>tr>th {
                          border-bottom-width: 2px;
                          vertical-align: bottom;
                          border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
                          padding: 8px;
                          text-align: left;
                        }
                        .table-bordered>tbody>tr>td{
                          padding: 8px;
                          vertical-align: top;
                          border: 1px solid #ddd;
                        }
                    .dataFilter{
                      display: block;
                      width: 800px;
                      margin: 20px auto;
                    }
                    
                    .inputGroup label,
                    .inputGroup input{
                        display: inline-block;
                        vertical-align: top;
                    }
                    .inputGroup + .inputGroup{
                        margin-top: 10px;
                    }
                    .inputGroup label{
                        width: 150px;
                    }
                    .inputGroup input{
                          font-family: arial;
                          font-size: 14px;
                          line-height: 30px;
                          display: inline-block;
                          vertical-align: top;
                          width: 263px;
                          padding: 0;
                          padding-left: 10px;
                          margin: 0;
                          height: 28px;

                          border: 1px solid #ccc;
                          border-radius: 4px;
                          color: #a9abaa;
                          outline: 0;
                    }
                    .dataFilter button{
                           border-radius: 5px;
                          font-size: 12px;
                          font-weight: 200;
                          height: 25px;
                          width: 70px;
                          border: 0;
                          outline: 0;
                          cursor: pointer;
                          background-color: #ccc;
                    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="dataFilter" action="#" method="post" name="">
                    <div class="inputGroup">
                        <label for="startDate">Start Date</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="startDate" id="startDate" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="inputGroup">
                        <label for="endDate">End Date</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="endDate" id="endDate" />
                    </div>
                    <button id="submitAction">Submit</button>
                </form>
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table-bordered">
           <thead>
               <th>S.no</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Email ID</th>
               <th>Mobile  No</th>
               <th>Date</th>
           </thead>
           <tbody id="userData">
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Rohit</td>
                            <td>sachin.raghaddv@xynmz.in</td>
                            <td>9654798949</td>
                            <td>2015-07-21</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Rohit</td>
                            <td>sachin.raghaddv@xynmz.in</td>
                            <td>9654798949</td>
                            <td>2015-07-08</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Rohit</td>
                            <td>sachin.raghaddv@xynmz.in</td>
                            <td>9654798949</td>
                            <td>2015-07-15</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Rohit</td>
                            <td>sachin.raghaddv@xynmz.in</td>
                            <td>9654798949</td>
                            <td>2015-07-21</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Rohit</td>
                            <td>sachin.raghaddv@xynmz.in</td>
                            <td>9654798949</td>
                            <td>2015-07-09</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Rohit</td>
                            <td>sachin.raghaddv@xynmz.in</td>
                            <td>9654798949</td>
                            <td>2015-07-12</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Rohit</td>
                            <td>sachin.raghaddv@xynmz.in</td>
                            <td>9654798949</td>
                            <td>2015-06-22</td>
                        </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
```

Comment: try this ...https://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dateRange.html

Comment: Do you expect that the start and end date will be entered in the same format as used in the table (yyyy-MM-dd)?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var tableDateCellIndex = 4;

  $('#submitAction').on('click', function (evt) {

    var startDate = parseDate($('#startDate').val());
    var endDate = parseDate($('#endDate').val());


    if (isNaN(startDate.getDate()) || isNaN(endDate.getDate())) {
      alert("Please fill the correct start and end date");
    } else {

      var rows = $("#userData").find("tr");

      $.each(rows, function (index, row) {
        var rowDate = parseDate($($(row).find("td")[tableDateCellIndex]).text());

        if (rowDate < startDate || rowDate > endDate) {
          // could take an action other than hiding the row with the date outside of the specified range
          $(row).hide();
        }

      });

    }

    return false;

  });

  // parse a date in yyyy-mm-dd format
  function parseDate(input) {
    var parts = input.split('-');
    // new Date(year, month [, day [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
    return new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2]); 
  }


});
```